# Intersection of two sets in openstreetmap to find parent of any area

Tags: openstreetmap, intersection, query, overpass-api, extract

I am trying to determine what the parent administrative area of any given area. The idea is that the closest parent is the administrative area with the highest/deepest admin_level that is shared as a parent by all points of the area boundary. Her the pseudo-algorithm I would like to be able to reproduce with the OSM API.

For a given area:
For *n* in all nodes of its boundaries:

- *parents* are the administrative area the node *n* lies in

*potential_parent* = intersect(list of *parents*)

*unique_parent* = *parent* in *potential_parent* where admin_level == min(admin_level)

Unfortunately I wasn't able to define the intersection of the different sets of parents for each node composing the boundary of the area of interest

Hehre is the solution I came up with:

```
rel(426391772) -> .obj;
.obj>;
is_in;
area._[boundary=administrative] -> .parents;
foreach .parents -> .shared(
  (.shared; - (.shared; - ._;););
);
out tags;
```

The for loop was my attempt to create the intersection set. But it doesn't return anything, while the *.parents* set is not empty.
I suspect the difference is not working as I thing it would.

The rest of the request to filter the good area is as follow and seems to work:

```
area.shared[boundary=administrative](if:t["admin_level"] == max(t["admin_level"]));
```

If you have a better approach to this problem, I am happy to hear it.

Here is an example of my request with the [turbo-overpass](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/GDe).

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989459/intersection-of-two-sets-in-openstreetmap-to-find-parent-of-any-area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following approach, which assumes to have at least one node with tags inside your relation. It restricts the output to adminsitrative boundaries.

```
rel(1681994) -> .r;
.r map_to_area;
(node[~"."~"."](area); - (.r;way(r);node(w);););
is_in;
area._[boundary=administrative];
area._(if:number(t["admin_level"]) < number (r.set(t["admin_level"])));
area._(if:number(t["admin_level"]) == max(number(t["admin_level"])));
rel(pivot);
out;
```

**NOTICE**: This sort of query is very expensive. Don't use it in any app unless you're happy to hammer your own Overpass API instance!

In general, I highly recommend to do this sort of query with a GIS database, like Postgresql with Postgis instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here, especially line 3 and 6. Can you explicit it?

I will probably use it for a fairly big amount of data. Do you recommend to go for a cheaper top down approach, but requiring more numerous queries or tu use postgresql/postgis (that requires to download the dataset before doing queries right?)? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Row 3: find node inside relation area, excluding the nodes of the relation itself.
Row 4: determine areas for nodes of previous step.
Row 5: Filter for boundary=administrative
Row 6: Find all areas where admin_level is lower than the one in row 1.

Comment: What exactly is your use case, and how many queries do you want to run? You could easily precalculate this data once in Postgis.

Comment: Thank you for the details. I would like to build a database containing hierarchical relationships between administrative areas (e.g. city, children districts, children neighbourhoods...). It is sometimes contained in relation, but sometimes this relation is not given, therefore I would like to be able to extract it from the geographic information. This for entire countries. While this data can be found of official portals I really would like to use osm data to be able to do that for multiple countries and more easily add other osm data.

Comment: There are OSM projects out there doing just that: https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Comment: This project is very interesting. I probably didn't consider it enough, but I would like to be able to also find the parent of non administrative boundaries (historic, surbubs, neighbourhood). I am going to try a mixed solution with a simplest request and more computation in python.

Comment: Anyway, your original question is answered, as you've asked for an approach using Overpass API. Your question didn't mention any requirement as to which data volume you expect.